# Why aren't my variables in an array printing? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Okay, me again. for those who did not see my last question, I am designing a data acquisition system in HTML. I wrote a bunch of code already and the basic concept of it is to click buttons to increase hidden counters, and then at the end print a bunch of variables in a way that it could easily be added to a .csv file. it's working amazingly, except for the export section. when I have it print it only displays

> [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

when I need it to display

> variableoutput1, variableoutput2, variableoutput3, variableoutput4, variableoutput5,

the code currently looks like this:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var Match = prompt("What is the match number? type numbers only");
  var Team = prompt("Which team are you scouting? type numbers only");
</script>


<!-- this is the script to copy and paste for each button-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var BUTTON1 = 0;
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var BUTTON2 = 0;
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var BUTTON3 = 0;
</script>

<button onclick="BUTTON1++">Increment1</button>
<button onclick="BUTTON2++">Increment2</button>
<button onclick="BUTTON3++">Increment3</button>

<script type="text/javascript">  
var stockData = [
    {Team},
    {Match},
    {BUTTON1},
    {BUTTON2},
    {BUTTON3},
  ];

</script>

<button onclick="document.write(stockData)">Export</button>
```

thank you to anyone who can help

Comment: have you tried JSON.stringify(yourdata)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you do not need multiple script tag, You can use only 1 script tag, Secondly doing this `{}` will treat the value as object. So remove that and use as variable only

```js
var Match = prompt("What is the match number? type numbers only");
var Team = prompt("Which team are you scouting? type numbers only");
var BUTTON1 = 0;
var BUTTON2 = 0;
var BUTTON3 = 0;
var stockData = [Team, Match, BUTTON1, BUTTON2, BUTTON3];
```

```html
<button onclick="BUTTON1++">Increment1</button>
<button onclick="BUTTON2++">Increment2</button>
<button onclick="BUTTON3++">Increment3</button>



<button onclick="document.write(stockData)">Export</button>
```

Comment: okay, we're getting a lot closer. The variables aren't updating but it is exporting amazingly (Thank you so much for that).